# Weird pronunciation of the word "of" in Russians by Sting

Tags: lyrics, language

The song Russians by String [contains the following line](https://youtu.be/wHylQRVN2Qs?t=71):

> Regardless of ideology

I listened to the song dozens of times by now, and Sting pronounce the word "of" in that sentence in a way that sounds like "vai". I kept listening, and just couldn't figure any logical reason for this.

I thought it might be "by", but "Regardless by ideology" doesn't make sense as well. (And no results in a search.)

Does anyone have any idea why String pronounce it in this way?

Comment: @xhienne thanks for the edit, thought about it as well but didn't do it myself. :)

Answer (score 5):

(caveat: I'm not a native English speaker)

Your are not mistaken, there is a "vai". Actually, [what I hear](https://youtu.be/wHylQRVN2Qs?t=71) is:

> regardlessovi[pause]deology

Your "vai" is actually the end of "of" ([pronounced with an ending /v/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of#Pronunciation)) directly bound to the "i" ([pronouced /aɪ/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ideology#Pronunciation)) of "ideology".